# Exception while Initializing for Singleton DBInitService

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship, bean-validation

While I was running my app, the exception was thrown as follows:

> 严重:   Exception while loading the app
> 严重:   Undeployment failed for context /wren6-fp
> 严重:   Exception while loading the app : jakarta.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton DBInitService
> jakarta.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton DBInitService

```
Caused by: jakarta.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Exception thrown from bean: jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException: One or more Bean Validation constraints were violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event: prePersist for class: edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.Order. Please refer to the embedded constraint violations for details.
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2386)
```

But can anyone tell me how to find the specific violations?
Here is my Order Entity code:

```
package edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.NamedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.PastOrPresent;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK_ORDERS")
@NamedQuery(name="Order.findAll", query="select o from Order o")
public class Order {

    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderType type;

    @PastOrPresent
    @Column(name = "ORDER_DATE")
    private LocalDate date;

    @PastOrPresent
    @Column(name = "ORDER_TIME")
    private LocalTime time;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ORDER_SUBJECTS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID"))
    private List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();

    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "HOLDER_ID")
    private Holder holder;

    /**
     * Get the value of subjects
     *
     * @return the value of subjects
     */
    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of subjects
     *
     * @param subjects new value of subjects
     */
    public void setSubjects(List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(OrderType type, LocalDate date, LocalTime time) {
        this.type = type;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    // relationship helper methods
    public void addSubject(Subject s) {
        if (!this.subjects.contains(s)) {
            this.subjects.add(s);
        }
        if (!s.getOrders().contains(this)) {
            s.getOrders().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeSubject(Subject s) {
        if (this.subjects.contains(s)) {
            this.subjects.remove(s);
        }
        if (s.getOrders().contains(this)) {
            s.getOrders().remove(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of subject
     *
     * @return the value of subject
     */
    /**
     * Set the value of subject
     *
     * @param subject new value of subject
     */
    /**
     * Get the value of holder
     *
     * @return the value of holder
     */
    public Holder getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of holder
     *
     * @param holder new value of holder
     */
    public void setHolder(Holder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Order other = (Order) obj;

        if ((this.id == null) || (other.id == null)) {
            return false;
        }

        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of time
     *
     * @return the value of time
     */
    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of time
     *
     * @param time new value of time
     */
    public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of date
     *
     * @return the value of date
     */
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of date
     *
     * @param date new value of date
     */
    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of type
     *
     * @return the value of type
     */
    public OrderType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of type
     *
     * @param type new value of type
     */
    public void setType(OrderType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id
     *
     * @return the value of id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id
     *
     * @param id new value of id
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order{" + "id=" + id + ", type=" + type + ", date=" + date + ", time=" + time + '}';
    }

}
```

The code in DBInitService.java is :

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.service;

import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.GenderType;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.Holder;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.Order;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.OrderType;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.Stock;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.Subject;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.domain.SubjectCategory;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.security.Group;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.security.GroupService;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.security.User;
import edu.iit.sat.itmd4515.wren6.security.UserService;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.ejb.EJB;
import jakarta.ejb.Singleton;
import jakarta.ejb.Startup;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Startup
@Singleton
public class DBInitService {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DBInitService.class.getName());

    @EJB
    private HolderService holderSvc;
    @EJB
    private OrderService orderSvc;
    @EJB
    private StockService stockSvc;
    @EJB
    private SubjectService subjectSvc;

    @EJB
    private GroupService groupSvc;
    @EJB
    private UserService userSvc;

    public DBInitService() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postContruct() {
        LOG.info("DBInitService.postConstruct");

        // security realm / indentity store data population
        Group adminGroup = new Group("ADMIN_GROUP", "This is a security realm group representing system administrators");
        Group holderGroup = new Group("HOLDER_GROUP", "This is a security realm group representing system holders(burrowers)");
        Group subjectGroup = new Group("SUBJECT_GROUP", "This is a security realm group representing system subject(operators)");

        groupSvc.create(adminGroup);
        groupSvc.create(holderGroup);
        groupSvc.create(subjectGroup);

        User admin = new User("admin", "admin", true);
        admin.addGroup(adminGroup);
        userSvc.create(admin);

        User sub1 = new User("sub1", "sub1", true);
        sub1.addGroup(subjectGroup);
        sub1.addGroup(adminGroup);
        userSvc.create(sub1);

        User sub2 = new User("sub2", "sub2", true);
        sub2.addGroup(subjectGroup);
        userSvc.create(sub2);

        User h1 = new User("h1", "h1", true);
        h1.addGroup(holderGroup);
        userSvc.create(h1);

        User h2 = new User("h2", "h2", true);
        h2.addGroup(holderGroup);
        userSvc.create(h2);

// Create entities and insert sample data
        Subject subject1 = new Subject(
                "Theory of relativity",
                "Albert Einstein",
                SubjectCategory.PHYSICS,
                "ISBN: 1604132949",
                LocalDate.of(1936, 2, 18)
        );
        subject1.setUser(sub1);
        
        Subject subject2 = new Subject(
                "Harry Potter",
                "J.K. Rolling",
                SubjectCategory.SCIENCE,
                "ISBN: 1604232948",
                LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 18)
        );
        subject1.setUser(sub2);
        
        Subject subject3 = new Subject(
                "Dark Ducks",
                "Douglas Adams",
                SubjectCategory.LITERATURE,
                "ISBN: 16042325898",
                LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 18)
        );

        Subject subject4 = new Subject(
                "Spare",
                "Prince Harry",
                SubjectCategory.MATHEMATICS,
                "ISBN: 9780593593806",
                LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 10)
        );

        Stock stock1 = new Stock(25);
        Stock stock2 = new Stock(18);
        Stock stock3 = new Stock(36);
        Stock stock4 = new Stock(58);

        stock1.setSubject(subject1);
        stock2.setSubject(subject2);
        stock3.setSubject(subject3);
        stock4.setSubject(subject4);

        stockSvc.create(stock1);
        stockSvc.create(stock2);
        stockSvc.create(stock3);
        stockSvc.create(stock4);

        subjectSvc.create(subject1);
        subjectSvc.create(subject2);
        subjectSvc.create(subject3);
        subjectSvc.create(subject4);

        Holder holder1 = new Holder(
                "Ryan Ren",
                "ryan.ren@iit.com",
                254854445,
                "8618221737351",
                GenderType.MALE
        );
        holder1.setUser(h1);

        Holder holder2 = new Holder(
                " Elon Musk",
                "elon.musk@tesla.com",
                29645138,
                "1618221731",
                GenderType.MALE
        );
        holder2.setUser(h2);

        Holder holder3 = new Holder(
                "Alice Walton",
                "alice.walton@walton.com",
                296388147,
                "161559731",
                GenderType.FEMALE
        );
        holder3.setUser(sub2);
     

        Holder holder4 = new Holder(
                "Abigail Johnson",
                "abigail.johnson@fidelity.com",
                286529185,
                "181779364",
                GenderType.FEMALE
        );
      

        Order order1 = new Order(
                OrderType.PRESERVED,
                LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 19),
                LocalTime.of(01, 19)
        );

        Order order2 = new Order(
                OrderType.RETURNED,
                LocalDate.of(2001, 2, 01),
                LocalTime.of(18, 21)
        );

        Order order3 = new Order(
                OrderType.PURCHASED,
                LocalDate.of(2011, 2, 21),
                LocalTime.of(19, 36)
        );

        Order order4 = new Order(
                OrderType.PRESERVED,
                LocalDate.of(2022, 4, 12),
                LocalTime.of(15, 29)
        );

        holder1.addOrder(order1);
        holder2.addOrder(order2);
        holder3.addOrder(order3);
        holder4.addOrder(order4);

        holderSvc.create(holder1);
        holderSvc.create(holder2);
        holderSvc.create(holder3);
        holderSvc.create(holder4);

        order1.setHolder(holder1);
        order2.setHolder(holder2);
        order3.setHolder(holder3);
        order4.setHolder(holder4);

        order1.addSubject(subject1);
        order2.addSubject(subject2);
        order3.addSubject(subject3);
        order4.addSubject(subject4);

        orderSvc.create(order1);
        orderSvc.create(order2);
        orderSvc.create(order3);
        orderSvc.create(order4);

        // write output of persisted sample data - also nevigating relationships
        for (Order o : orderSvc.findAll()) {
            LOG.info(o.toString());

            LOG.info("Order Holder ***************************************");

            LOG.info("\t\t" + o.getHolder().toString());

            LOG.info("Order Subjects ****************************************");
            for (Subject s : o.getSubjects()) {
                LOG.info("\t\t" + s.toString());
                LOG.info("\t\t\t" + s.getCreator().toString());
                LOG.info("\t\t\t" + s.getIdentifier().toString());
                LOG.info("\t\t\t" + s.getTitle().toString());
                LOG.info("\t\t\t" + s.getCategory().toString());
                LOG.info("\t\t\t" + s.getCreateDate().toString());
            }

        }

        for (Holder h : holderSvc.findAll()) {
            LOG.info(h.toString());

            LOG.info("Holder Orders ************");

            for (Order o : h.getOrders()) {
                LOG.info("\t\t" + o.toString());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I tested Order entity. If create only one row, nothing will be wrong, only if more than 2 rows will generate this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just positioned my Order Entity to find my error. After modifying the validaiton constraints, everything is ok now.
Thank you guys!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).